# In scrapy+selenium, how to make a spider request to wait until previous request has finished processing?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy, request

## TL;DR

In scrapy, I want the Request to wait till all spider parse callbacks finish. So the whole process needs to be sequential. Like this:

```
Request1 -> Crawl1 -> Request2 -> Crawl2 ...
```

But what is happening now:

```
Request1 -> Request2 -> Request3 ...
            Crawl1      
                        Crawl2
                                 Crawl3 ...
```

## Long version

I am new to scrapy + selenium web scraping.
I am trying to scrape a website where the contents are being updated heavily with javascript. Firstly I am opening the website with selenium and logging in. After that, I am creating a using a downloader middleware that handles the requests with selenium and returns the responses. Below is the middleware's `process_request` implementation:

```py
class XYZDownloaderMiddleware:
    '''Other functions are as is. I just changed this one'''
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        driver = request.meta['driver']

        # We are opening a new link
        if request.meta['load_url']:
            driver.get(request.url)
            WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, request.meta['wait_for_xpath'])))
        # We are clicking on an element to get new data using javascript.
        elif request.meta['click_bet']:
            element = request.meta['click_bet']
            element.click()
            WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, request.meta['wait_for_xpath'])))

        body = driver.page_source
        return HtmlResponse(driver.current_url, body=body, encoding="utf-8", request=request)
```

In settings, I have also set `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1` so that, multiple `driver.get()` do not called and selenium can peacefully load responses one by one.

Now what I see happening is selenium opens each URL, scrapy lets selenium wait for the response to finish loading and then middleware returns the response properly (goes to `if response.meta['load_url']` block).

But, after I got the response, I want to use the selenium driver (in the `parse(response)` functions) to click on each of the elements by yielding a Request and return the updated HTML from the middleware (the `elif request.meta['click_bet']` block).

The Spider is minimally like this:

```
class XYZSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def start_requests(self):
        start_urls = [
            'https://www.example.com/a',
            'https://www.example.com/b'
        ]
        self.driver = self.getSeleniumDriver()
        for url in start_urls:
            request = scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
            request.meta['driver'] = self.driver
            request.meta['load_url'] = True
            request.meta['wait_for_xpath'] = '/div/bla/bla'
            request.meta['click_bet'] = None
            yield request


    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.xpath('//a/@href').getall()
        for url in start_urls:
            request = scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.rightSectionParse)
            request.meta['driver'] = self.driver
            request.meta['load_url'] = True
            request.meta['wait_for_xpath'] = '//div[contains(@class, "rightSection")]'
            request.meta['click_bet'] = None
            yield request
    def rightSectionParse(self, response):
        ...
```

So what is happening is, scrapy is not waiting for the spider to parse. Scrapy gets the response, and then parallelly calls parse callback and next fetch response. But selenium driver needs to be used by the parse callback function before the next request processing.

I want the requests to wait until the parse callback is finished.

Comment: I say don't use selenium for crawling, you can handle it with **Scrapy** itself.

Comment: How will you handle the dynamic contents that are loaded in js? And how will you click on an element and call `onclick` function in js to do ajax and get more dynamic contents to parse? And how will you login to the website with credentials and captcha?

Comment: first of all you look at the source page which js is not executed in. after that find APIs which are called to see data they pass. by clicking `onclick` you will go to another page which may have expected url or can make it somehow and request to it, otherwise if you really have to click on it better use selenium. in order to insert captcha you can use OCR to find the captcha value, but if it is like google captcha it wouldn't be that easy.

Comment: Numerous things can be done in a single `onclick` or other events in js. I do not think it is feasible in this way. Obviously, you can also execute the js events on the site from scrapy, but these are out of the scope of this question. The question is how to make the crawling and requesting serial.